# migrating berkeley database from XP to linux box

Tags: linux, ubuntu, database

I am in the process of migrating from XP to Linux (Unbuntu 9.10).

I need to migrate a larg(ish) BDB database (approx 5Gb) from my XP machine to the Linux machine).

The berkeley database was created using version 4.7.25 of the berkeley library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 9.10 has libraries and utilities to deal with the db. You can install them like this:

`sudo apt-get install db4.7-util db4.7-doc libdb4.7`

You should be able to just move the file over and start working with it.